# Windows 8.1 does not load while dual booting Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 07/19/2014

Tags: dual-boot, 14.04, system-installation, windows-8, uefi

I am new to the Linux/Ubuntu world and I am interested in continuing, but from the beginning I am already having problems with dual booting a preinstalled Windows 8.1 with Ubuntu. I have a Lenovo IdeaPad p500 touch 64-bit 6GB RAM 1TB hard drive preinstalled with Windows 8 and a few weeks ago updated to Windows 8.1.

I installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS on a USB and booted from there. So far Ubuntu works perfectly (I'm still learning though), but Windows 8.1 does not load anymore. When I restart my computer these are the options I see:

- Ubuntu
- Ubuntu advanced mode
- Windows Boot Manager (on /dev/sda2)
- System setup

Then when I select Windows Boot Manager (on /dev/sda2), a black screen appears with this error

```
error: file`/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi' not found.
Press any key to continue..._
```

I have tried to run Boot Repair from the terminal by typing `boot-repair`, but then I get this error:

```
/usr/share/boot-sav/gui-g2slaunch.sh: line 33: hash: gksudo: not found  
/usr/share/boot-sav/gui-g2slaunch.sh: line 35: hash: gksu: not found
```

I have tried to burn boot-repair-64-bit-iso on a CD and boot from it, but there is no option to boot from a CD in the BIOS.

This is some information about my partitions if it helps:

```
NAME    FSTYPE  LABEL           MOUNTPOINT NAME      SIZE OWNER GROUP MODE
sda                                        sda     931.5G root  disk  brw-rw----
├─sda1  ntfs    WINRE_DRV                  ├─sda1   1000M root  disk  brw-rw----
├─sda2  vfat    SYSTEM_DRV      /boot/efi  ├─sda2    260M root  disk  brw-rw----
├─sda3  vfat    LRS_ESP                    ├─sda3   1000M root  disk  brw-rw----
├─sda4                                     ├─sda4    128M root  disk  brw-rw----
├─sda5  ntfs    Windows8_OS                ├─sda5  792.7G root  disk  brw-rw----
├─sda6  ntfs                               ├─sda6    450M root  disk  brw-rw----
├─sda7  ntfs    LENOVO                     ├─sda7     25G root  disk  brw-rw----
├─sda8  ntfs    PBR_DRV                    ├─sda8     20G root  disk  brw-rw----
├─sda9                                     ├─sda9    1.9G root  disk  brw-rw----
└─sda10 ext4                    /          └─sda10  89.1G root  disk  brw-rw----
sr0     iso9660 Boot-Repair-Disk 64bit
                                /media/ubu sr0     507.9M root  cdrom brw-rw----
```

Please respond as **simply** and in as detailed a fashion as possible. Thanks and I appreciate the help in advance!!!

Comment: Can you still boot Windows through the efi boot menu? That's the menu you get from some function key (or ESC, or DEL, varies by machine) offering you the choice of boot devices or OSes.

Comment: YOU ARE THE MAN DUDE! Honestly I checked the Efi boot menu before and what I saw was this: ubuntu, Ubuntu, EFI Network 0 for IPv4, EFI Network 0 for IPv6. I found it weird to have 2 ubuntu but just thought they where the same. So I would just select out of the two EFI instead and both displayed "Checking media" then it would revert to Grub. Thanks to you this time around when I checked,I decided to select Ubuntu with the capital U. Thats where windows 8.1 was installed. Do I have to boot through efi to get windows 8? Is there a way to change this? Like straight from Grub instead? Thanks a ton!

Comment: Als,o like stated before there are two ubuntus in my efi boot menu. One of them is actually windows 8. Can I change the name from Ubuntu to windows 8 from the efi boot menu? Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

From the Ubuntu side, install the efibootmgr package, and check its man page

```
sudo apt-get install efibootmgr
man efibootmgr
```

You should be able to both rename entries, and reorder them if you want.

```
efibootmgr -v
```

will show you what is actually being run, so you can see the name of the bootloader file being used for Windows (bootmgfw.efi was the original name, might have been renamed by boot-repair).